# safari ReferenceError: Can't find variable

Tags: javascript, safari, referenceerror

I have the following in its own DIV

```
<script>
function newfunc()
{
alert("here");
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="newfunc()">Press me</button>
```

On IE and FF it works fine, but on Safari (at least Safari 4.0.5) it says “ReferenceError can't find variable” - now the content was loaded into the DIV dynamically and it seems Safari can't see the function definitions within this DIV - however, if I put the function `newfunc()` onto the main HTML page (i.e. not in the DIV) then the button press does call the function.

It’s as if Safari doesn't see the Javascript functions that have been added to the DIV.

Any help would be appreciated.

adam

Comment: If that's the case what do you expect us to do? Your only choice is to put the JS code in the main body. Tell us what language is your server side code, post your current code and we'll try to guide you through this.

Comment: its not possible to put all the functions into the main page as some functions contain dynamic content dependant on for example session data which is checked when the div content is loaded.

Comment: see http://www.gymadvisory.co.uk press Find Gyms it will probably display an unstyled page - this is because the button element has no type="button" attribute yet and because the jquery assigned click function tries to call javascript functions that it can't find it does a submit - adding the missing attribute will stop that but then pressing the button does nothing

Comment: also - once the unstyled page is displayed press back button and try again - it now should work ! not sure why the page gone back to should work

Comment: reverted back to previous version of app and seems ok so must be bug in javascript changes albeit still strange behaviour.

Comment: FYI it is possible to have server side code output appear wherever you want in the page, just store the output in variable then show its value in the desired place. What's your server side language?

Comment: Why you need to put JS function inside DIV? Whatever content (dynamic or static) you have in your javascript function, will not run until you call that function and you are calling that function only when that DIV's display is on. Can you clarify please? Thanks, Salekin

Answer (score 5):

Javascript that is added dynamically to a page needs to be eval-d in order to correctly initialise.

In order for that to work correctly for function definitions they need to be formatted slightly differently. eg:

```
<script>
newfunc = function()
{
alert("here");
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="newfunc()">Press me</button>
```

After adding the content to the DIV, extract all  tag elements from the DIV and eval their contents.

For example, using PrototypeJS (http://www.prototypejs.org/api/):

```
$(divid).innerHTML.evalScripts();
```

Where divid is the ID of the div you just populated with content.